# React-select defaultValue is not showing

Tags: reactjs, select, formik, react-select

I'm using Formik and React-select library and defaultValue is not working/taking effect and it remains empty, i don't know why this is happening.

**MySelectInput** component:

```
interface Props {
    // .. other props
    options: CategoryOptions[];
    defaultCategory: CategoryOptions;
}

const MySelectInput: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props.name);
    
    return (
        <>
            <Select
                options={props.options}
                isSearchable
                defaultValue={props.defaultCategory}
                onChange={(v) => helpers.setValue(v!.value)}
                onBlur={() => helpers.setTouched(true)}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                styles={customSelectStyles}
            />
        </>
    )
};

export default MySelectInput;
```

**Usage:**

```
<MySelectInput
   options={CategoryOptions}
   placeholder="Category"
   name="category"
   label="Category"
   defaultCategory={{ value: activity.category, label: activity.category }}
/>
```

My array of objects (CategoryOptions):

```
export const CategoryOptions: CategoryOptions[] = [
    { value: 'drinks', label: 'Drinks' },
    { value: 'music', label: 'Music' },
    { value: 'travel', label: 'Travel' },
];
```

The options are working and displaying well but defaultValue is not working. If i use static strings inside object properties like:

```
defaultCategory={{ value: "test", label: "test" }}
```

is working well. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably use an item from CategoryOptions.

Instead of

```
defaultValue={props.defaultCategory}
```

do

```
defaultValue={props.defaultCategory[0]}
```

I'm also wondering why your `CategoryOptions` object is same as the `CategoryOptions` type. Maybe you should rename it to `categoryOptions`

Comment: This is not working, because I set defaultCategory type as object and not as an array of objects, i passed an object as prop not an array, 

CategoryObject is of type 
`export interface CategoryOptions {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}`
i don't understand your question well?